# rubygem "Argument list too long"

Tags: rubygems

My problem is that during or after running a process which uses Ruby intensively, when I use any gem command including gem --version or gem install rake, it hangs for just over a minute and then gives me this error:

```
$ gem list
/Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem: line 5: /Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem: Argument list too long
/Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem: line 5: /Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem: Unknown error: 0
```

file at : line 5: /Users/username/.rvm/bin/gem

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -s "/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.8.7-p334" ]] ; then
  source "/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.8.7-p334"
  exec gem "$@"                # this is line 5
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-    1.8.7-p334'" >&2
exit 1
fi
```

The only way that I have found to get this working again is to restart my computer, which is obviously undesirable. I am using OSX 10.6.5

I have spent quite a while trying to find anyone else who has had this problem, and been unsuccessful. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you're calling your script recursively...

You can

1. Rename your script
2. Use the full /usr/bin/gem path to refer to rubygems

Edit: Bonus points and a magic cookie to whoever can tell me ***why*** her script is being called recursively. Just FYI it should not be happening under normal circumstances ;)

Comment: After several reboots and a period of time using my system ruby and rubygems (instead of various rvm versions) I just went back and tried to replicate this problem on every ruby that I have installed, but was unable to. I suspect that the original problem originated with one of the projects I've been working on in the last few months, but after some experimentation with running them I'm unable to figure out which. 

One of them was a shell script which ran several commands, wrote the bash history into itself, and performed logic upon the result. Rubygems was involved. Unreplicable break, tho.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me a fix. I'll test it out as soon as I can get replication on the problem.

Comment: It looks like it was a loop in .bash_brofile and .bashrc caused by installing other tools which automodified them.

Answer (score 37):

This issue is that you set rvm to use --default a nonexistent ruby version.

You have to specify it exactly, or it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This helped my find my issue: I don't actually have rake installed ;)

Comment: This solved it for me on OS X 10.8.3 right after I installed Ruby 2.0.0... after running "rvm --default use 2.0.0" the bundle command returned to normal.

Comment: This is the real problem/answer! I was getting all kinds of terminal lagginess from this and couldn't bundle anywhere. Great answer!

Answer (score 7):

Solved it by calling

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

istead of

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Everything works now.

Comment: Maybe messed up configurations, i really don't know

Comment: Fixed my problem too when trying to install jsduck gem

Answer (score 2):

I found this was because the permissions on /usr/local/rvm/rubies/$RUBY_VERSION/bin/gem where wrong. I corrected them by running:

```
sudo chown -R root:rvm /usr/local/rvm
```

You will also need to add your user to the rvm group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a YOUR_USERNAME rvm
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix this problem (when installing a gem) by using

```
     rvm all do gem install <gemname>
```

in your case it would be :

```
    rvm all do gem list
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error as well. For me it's solved by leaving the project folder and then go back into the project folder afterwards. I'm not sure why this works, but maybe it'll work for others too.

`cd ..`

`cd project`